# How to create website specific configuration files while running multiple ASP.NET websites on a single code base?

Tags: asp.net, codebase

I want to create 2 websites on a single code base in asp.net. 
lets for say :

[www.domain1.com](http://domain1.com)

[www.domain2.com](http://domain2.com)

I need to keep all the appsetting key name sames but with different values for each of the websites.So i need to maintain two web.config files in my code base.

After exploring on internet , i found to keep both of the web.config files in different folders in the code base.

Bow the problem is, how can i link each of the different web.config file with its corrosponding Virtual directory for each the website because both of the Virtual directories will target the same folder of code base.

I really neede it as i have to finish this work within this week.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to serve both site from one application/virtual directory, the only solution I can come up with is as follows:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="setting[www.domain1.com]" value="foo" />
  <add key="setting[www.domain2.com]" value="bar" />
  ...
```

And then access these accordingly:

```
var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting[" + request.Domain + "]"];
```

Comment: It's like adding up two keys for same work. Is not it? I dont want to maitain two keys for a work as it will impose a big code change on my team in the current code base. Rather i want to keep same key for a work for both of the websites to avoid major code changes. If it would be so simple, then i wouldn't ask such a question. Is not it Mr Anton ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Having twice as many keys in a single `web.config` is IMO better than having two separate `web.config`s with all the heavy duplication.